# How to find no of I/Os of a program in stxxl?

Tags: algorithm, memory-management, io, external, stxxl

I am using STXXL, can somebody help me in finding the no. of I/O's(or blocks transferred) done by my program(or algorithm or process)? I know how to restrict the memory usage by any particular process, but don't know how to restrict the block size in STXXL and how to count no. of blocks transferred.

Comment: most likely, no. = number

Answer (score 2):

The STXXL provides an **I/O Performance Counter**, see [here](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/tags/master/common_io_counter.html) which stores various measured I/O data (including the number of blocks transferred).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, [blktrace](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~aaronc/iosched/doc/blktrace.html) will keep track of block I/O for you. I don't know about other systems.